# Create scroll to ID without jQuery and with offsetTop -80px

Tags: javascript

I want when the user clicks any link with # in front of it to take them to a certain section of the same page that has that ID in the HTML code.

This solves my problem:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

Now though, since I have an 80px tall header I would like it to scroll down to the ID - 80px.

How can I apply this to the existing code? I would like to continue to use JavaScript.

Comment: You can’t really do that with `scrollIntoView`. You will need to determine the position of the element within the page, and then subtract your 80px from that value and scroll the document to that position.

Comment: Can you share with me a similar javascript code that allows this?

Comment: you can use element.offsetTop as a starting point

Comment: Can you show me an example code maybe in the reply? Thank you very much!

Comment: please see answers for example implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first find the position of element on page, then use scrollTo with adjusted top.

Note! this might not work, depending on your element positioning, fixed, static, etc...

```
const elementTop = (element) => {
  let offsetTop = element.offsetTop;

  // add offsetTops all the way to <body>
  let offsetParent = element.offsetParent;

  while(offsetParent) {
    offsetTop += offsetParent.offsetTop;
    offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
  }

  return offsetTop;
};

document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const targetEl = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href'));
    const targetElTop = elementTop(targetEl);
    
    window.scrollTo({ 
      top: targetElTop + 80, // your adjustments 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });
  });
});
```

[mdn scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)
[mdn offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent)

Comment: I don't think this code is right for me. Maybe I expressed myself wrong? I'm looking for a way to do a scroll to ID from the href to the ID attribute of an HTML element.

This here is a basic requirement and since I have to apply it to all pages the href has to be as generic as shown in my code.

Comment: let me edit a little, see if that helps. otherwise im understading the problem wrong

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes it is perfect! It just needs to be put "-80" in my case, but otherwise it works :)